# Find the eigenvalues with constant values in each row

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the eigenvalues of
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
C_1 & C_1 & C_1&\cdots&C_1 \\
C_2 & C_2 & C_2&\cdots &C_2 \\
C_3 & C_3 & C_3&\cdots&C_3 \\
\vdots&\ & \ & \ & \vdots\\
C_n & C_n & C_n&\cdots&C_n \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

My approach:
$$\left|
\begin{matrix}
C_1-λ & C_1 & C_1&...&C_1 \\
C_2 & C_2-λ & C_2&...&C_2 \\
C_3 & C_3 & C_3-λ&...&C_3 \\
\vdots & \ & \ & \ & \vdots\\
C_n & C_n & C_n&...&C_n-λ
\end{matrix}\right|
$$
and i eventually have 
\begin{align}
\ -λ^3 +(C_1+C_2+C_3)λ^2-C_1C_3λ-C_1C_2=0
\end{align}

and then I'm lost at this stage...

Comment: Hint: A lot of them are zero.

Comment: Should there also be dots between $C_3$ and $C_n$? Is this matrix square?

Comment: means 
\begin{align}
\ -λ^3=0
\end{align} ?

Comment: yeap, is a square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll work it out for $n=2$, $n=3$ and you can try to extrapolate (and figure out the pattern) from there:

$n=2$:

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}a&a\\b&b\end{array}\right)$$
$$\det(A-\lambda I) = \left|\begin{array}{cc}a-\lambda&a\\b&b-\lambda\end{array}\right|= (a-\lambda)(b-\lambda)-ab = \lambda^2-(a+b)\lambda$$
which has two roots, namely $\lambda = 0$, $\lambda = a+b$.

$n=3$:

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}a&a&a\\b&b&b\\c&c&c\end{array}\right)$$
\begin{align*}
\det(A-\lambda I) &= \left| \begin{array}{ccc}a-\lambda&a&a\\b&b-\lambda&b\\c&c&c-\lambda\end{array} \right|\\
&= (a-\lambda)\left|\begin{array}{cc}b-\lambda&b\\c&c-\lambda\end{array}\right| - a \left|\begin{array}{cc}b&b\\c&c-\lambda\end{array}\right| + a\left|\begin{array}{cc}b&b-\lambda\\c&c\end{array}\right|\\
&= (a-\lambda)[(b-\lambda)(c-\lambda) -bc] - a[b(c-\lambda)-bc] + a[bc-c(b-\lambda)]\\
&= (a-\lambda)(\lambda^2-(b+c)\lambda)+ a(b\lambda) + a(c\lambda)\\
&= \lambda^2(a+b+c) - a(b+c)\lambda-\lambda^3 + a(b+c)\lambda\\
&= -\lambda^3+(a+b+c)\lambda^2\\
&= -\lambda^2(\lambda - (a+b+c))
\end{align*}
which has three roots, namely $\lambda=0$, $\lambda=0$, $\lambda=a+b+c$.

The rest can be extrapolated from this. (I have included the desired result in the end, in case you want to see it, but you should try to convince yourself of the result before looking at this.)

---

By induction, you can prove that the matrix

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}C_1 & C_1 & \cdots & C_1\\
C_2&C_2&\cdots&C_2\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots& \vdots \\
C_n & C_n & \cdots & C_n \end{array}\right)$$

> has eigenvalues given by $\lambda=0$ with multiplicity $n-1$, and $\lambda = \sum_{k=1}^n C_k$ with multiplicity $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $rank(A)=1$, $A$ admits $n-1$ times the eigenvalues $0$. The last eigenvalue is $trace(A)=C_1+\cdots+C_n$.